# Max edit distance between binary strings of length n

Tags: binary, dynamic-programming

Given a binary string s of length $n>2$.An edit operation is a single character insert, delete or substitution. The edit distance between two strings is the minimum number of edit operations needed to transform one string into the other one. How can I calculate the max edit distance between the given binary string and all the binary strings with the same length $n$.

It's not hard for me to think about a Brute Force method to solve the problem in $O(2^n*n^2)$,however the solution is quite disappointing.
Any better ideas to solve the problem?

For some cases my BF solutions were:

- s="0111001010100"  answer=9 from "0000111111111"
- s="001100101"      answer=6 from "110000000"
- s="01110010101"    answer=7 from "00001111000"

There might be one or more than one valid strings with the same answer.

Comment: The algorithm of the edit/Levenshtein distance belongs to the family of "dynamic programming" algorithms. See [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/med.pdf)

Comment: Isn't the edit distance between two strings of length $n$ at most $n$? (I'm not sure where you got your $O(2^n\cdot n^2)$ estimate.)